# Trigger a state change

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have a channel list here. I added an onClick event on each of them. When the event takes place, the value of the target updates the payload of my selectChannel(selectedChannel) action. Only the reducer does not fire.
The action update the payload but the next state won't be update.

I don't really understand where is my mistake,
I created the action by a function
I used mapDispatchToProps to dispatch the action
mapStateToProps to select the data from the store.
I saw in my console the event work well, he change the payload of my
selectChannel(selectedChannel) action. 
But at this point my reducer won't work.

`````
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
    import { logger } from 'redux-logger';

    // internal modules
    import App from './components/app';
    import '../assets/stylesheets/application.scss';
    import messagesListReducer from './reducers/messages-list-reducer';
    import channelsListReducer from './reducers/channels-list-reducer';
    import selectedChanelReducer from './reducers/selected-channel-reducer';
    import currentUsernameReducer from './reducers/current-username-reducer';


    // State and reducers
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
    const middlewares = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(logger));

    const reducers = combineReducers({
      messages: messagesListReducer,
      channels: channelsListReducer,
      selectedChannel: selectedChanelReducer,
      currentUser: currentUsernameReducer
    });

    // render an instance of the component in the DOM
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {}, middlewares)}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );


    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


    import { listChannels, selectChannel } from '../actions';
    // import City from '../containers/city';


    class ListChannels extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="channels__list list" >
            <h2>Redux Chat</h2>
            {this.props.channelsList.map((channel) => {
              return (
                <div className="list" key={channel} onClick={() => this.props.selectChannel(channel)}>
                  <h4 >{channel}</h4>
                </div>
              );
            })
            }
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators(
        {
          listChannels: listChannels,
          selectChannel: selectChannel
        }, dispatch
      );
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        channelsList: state.channels,
        selectedChannel: state.selectedChannel
      };
    }


    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListChannels);



SelectedChannel reducer

    import { selectChannel, SELECT_CHANNEL } from '../actions/index';


    export default function (state = 'general', action) {
      if (state === undefined) {
        return ["he"];
      }
      // Here I tried to debug by this way, but I can't fin how to trigger, the reducer 

      if (action.type === SELECT_CHANNEL) {
        console.log(action.payload);
        return action.payload;
      }
      return state;
    }
    ````
    // TODO: add and export your own actions
    const initialState = {
      messages: [],
      channels: ['general', 'react', 'paris'],
      currentUser: prompt("What is your username?") || `anonymous${Math.floor(10 + (Math.random() * 90))}`,
      selectedChannel: 'general'
    };

    const MESSAGE = 'MESSAGE';
    const SET_CHANNELS = 'SET_CHANNELS';
    const SET_USER = 'SET_USER';
    const SELECT_CHANNEL = 'SELECT_CHANNEL';

    export default SELECT_CHANNEL;

    export function setMessages(messages) {
      return {
        type: MESSAGE,
        payload: messages
      };
    }

    export function listChannels() {
      return {
        type: SET_CHANNELS,
        payload: initialState.channels
      };
    }

    export function setUser() {
      return {
        type: SET_USER,
        payload: initialState.currentUser
      };
    }

    export function selectChannel(selectedChannel) {
      return {
        type: SELECT_CHANNEL,
        payload: selectedChannel
      };
    }
`````

Answer (score 0):

I didn't export the variable who defined the action.type.